# Extracting Country Code From Mobile Number

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP port of Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) to create a form validator to check if the inputted mobile number is valid before dispatching an SMS to the user.

The problem is I need to allow the user to enter the number in 2 ways. Either the number without the country code, or with the country code:

```
07700000000
+447700000000
```

When the user enters `07700000000` I need to match that to a country code.

Facebook do this. They allow you to sign up with mobile and you can enter a number without the country code. I'm doing something similar by giving the user an option to register with mobile or email using a single form element. The user can enter either an email or mobile into a single input.

The problem is LibPhoneNumber can't extract the country code from a number that doesn't contain one.

Here's my validator:

```
class EmailOrMobile extends AbstractRule {

    public function validate($input)
    {
        $phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();

        /*
         * Is the input a valid email address?
         */
        if(v::email()->validate($input))
        {
            return true;
        }

        /*
         * Is the input a valid phone number?
         */
        $phoneNumber = $phoneNumberUtil->parse($input, null);
        if($phoneNumberUtil->isValidNumber($phoneNumber))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This works when the number is entered with a country code, but not when it isn't.

Is it possible to extract a country code from a mobile number? And if not how are Facebook doing it?

Comment: Just remove the last 10 digits of the number. Whatever's left (if anything) is the country code. Or check if the length of the number string is greater than 10 to see if it has a country code .

Comment: If I remove the last 7 from `07700000000` that gives me `0770`. But the country code for the UK is `+44`. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Last 10 digits, not 7. It would be either 0s or +CC. Assuming all the mobile numbers of the world are 10 digits.

Comment: BugHunterUK is asking how to get the country from a 10 digit phone number(that doesn't already have the country prefix), now if you remove 10 from a number without the prefix you are left with nothing

Comment: @RaulCuth yes this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @BugHunterUK I edited my comment. Remove the last 10 if you know both formats will have an area code. In the second, you'll have "+44" left, so you know it has a country code to validate.  The first one will have a 0 left, is that a typo? Without a country code, I'd expect the number to be 10 digits long, but the first number has 11 digits.

Comment: I see that not many people understand this question :)

Comment: @Carcigenicate I need to get the country code for number that don't contain one. For example `07700000000` is a UK number. That number doesn't contain a country code, but I need to get the country code for that number.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misunderstood. I don't think that would be possible. Facebook likely does it by asking for your country, looking up the code, then adding it for you.

Comment: I thought that it would be possible to reverse check where the phone number comes from(without the prefix) but I think that there are legal issues here. As for how Facebook does it, remember that Facebook already has information about you, like country of origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but i highly doubt this is possible mainly because of legal issues(reverse check will not work i guess). One way I think you could manage to pull this off is to ask for country of origin when asking users to write down their phone number.

Something like a dropdown of countries just before the phone number input field, and in the backend you could build the full phone number by adding the prefix according to the selected country.

Also, to make sure they don't select country and then also write down the prefix, validate the phone number field with some regex, max 10 digits, or something like that.

I hope this helps and if I find something better, I'll keep you updated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Every Country has differenc codes
for example USA and Canada is +1 Russia is +7, but France is +33, Armenia is +374
so there are different number count in each country and there are some countryes with same area codes it is easy to save country code and regional codes sometimes to get which country is it.